# Cannot bind mat-autocomplete value to my input type text

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to design a table with lot of input fields of type text.

I have a mat-autocomplete which fetches data based on row information.

For some reason when i click on an option generated by mat autocomplete the input value is not updated.

Here is my HTML

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let set of sets; let i = index" [matColumnDef]="set.name">
            <th  mat-header-cell 
                *matHeaderCellDef
                (mouseenter)="setPosition(i)">
                    <div >
                        <h4>{{set.name | titlecase}} <span style="cursor: pointer" (click)="editSet(set)" class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span   cdkDropList
                        [cdkDropListData]="type"
                        (cdkDropListDropped)="addType($event, i)" *ngFor="let type of set.types; let isLast=last" cdkDrag>{{types.number}}{{isLast ? '' : ', '}}</span> 
                    </div>
            </th>
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
              <input id="uniqueId" *ngIf="condition"
                placeholder="Enter Details"
                ngModel
                (ngModelChange)="getNumbersOfRowId(row.id, $event)"
                [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                [(ngModel)]="this.set.types[findIndex(set.types, row.id)].number" 
                [matAutocomplete]="auto" 
                (focusout)="saveNumber(sets[i], row)" 
                type="text">

                <input id="empty"
                placeholder="Disabled, drag number to enable"
                *ngIf="this.set.types.length === 0"
                [disabled]="this.set.types.length === 0"
                  type="text" >
              <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let number of filteredNumbers" [value]="number">
                    {{number}}
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-autocomplete>
            </td>
 </ng-container>
```

**Type Script**

```
getNumbersOfRowId(id: number, event: any) {

if( this.rowId!== id) {
  this.rowId= id;
  this.numbers= [];
  this.filteredNumbers= [];

  this.service.getNumberFormRowId(id, event)
  .subscribe(res => {
    this.numbers = res;
    this.filteredNumbers = res;
  })
}
```

}

Comment: Is this inside a `<form>`? Are there any console errors? What is `*ngIf="condition"`? What is the second `<input>` for?

Comment: Hey, i am not using <form> tags, if it helps i have found the root cause of my issue

As you can see i am saving a number after focusout on the input field.
When i click on the options generated by the Autocomplete my input is getting focused out and the input field is getting binded again with the orginal value

I am looking on how to overcome this issue, Any help would be appriciated

Comment: What you have is a fair bit more complicated than a standard autocomplete. You have several things that apparently interact and affect one another, and without seeing how all that works (we'd need to see all the relevant code) it's not possible to make any recommendations other than don't use the focus out - use the autocomplete selection event instead.

Comment: Don't post the same question twice [Save on (focusout) with angular mat-autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57224315/save-on-focusout-with-angular-mat-autocomplete)