# Save on (focusout) with angular mat-autocomplete

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a simple input with autocomplete

```
<input [matAutocomplete]="auto" (focusout)="save()">
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let number of numbers" [value]="number">
     {{number}}
   </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

I want to save the input value when the user is no longer using the input field

The issue is when i am clicking on a autocomplete option focusout function of input field is called.

What are my options to save input value which checks both autocomplete and input field status

Thankyou

Comment: You want to *save* it where?

Comment: Hey Nicholas i am calling a service which saves the value in the Database, The actual implementation is very big but i found out the root cause of my problem to be this

Comment: Why would you want to save on focusout? Users may interact several times before being 'done'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ONLY want to handle the clicking on autocomplete option you should use `(click)` on that option to handle it.

```
<input [matAutocomplete]="auto">
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
   <mat-option (click)="save(number)" *ngFor="let number of numbers" [value]="number">
     {{number}}
   </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

However, if you want to do it with focus, this will work:

```
<input #myInput (focusout)="save(myInput.value)" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let number of numbers" [value]="number">
     {{number}}
   </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-autocomplete-obf7el?file=app%2Fautocomplete-overview-example.html)

Comment: Hey Dino, the solution you have provided works for static data and does not work for my scenario.
I should have given a more detailed question from the start sorry for that. I want to save input field data when ever user loses focus(that is the requirement). My mat autocomplete fetches data from an API service and is different for each row of my table.
When a user makes a selection from my options list the input loses its focus and the save method is called (I however want to perform a check here to see if mat option list is opened)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a way we can do that,

```
<input [matAutocomplete]="auto" matInput (focusout)="onFocusOut()" [formControl]="autoInput">
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let number of numbers" [value]="number">
      {{number}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

here is the code, I have added a `formControl` to bind autoComplete value to a variable.
And here is the way, we can access the `matInput` value after `matInput` is focused out, then we can perform some operations like autoSelect a value or filter options, etc. to manipulate autocomplete input value.

```
// since focusout will be called after optionSelected event called of 
// matAutoComplete, we are adding timeOut to delay focusOut operations
// and so we will have the true value of autoInput

onFocusOut() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    let input = this.autoInput.value;
    // filtering matching values from options and 
    // selecting first matched or set the default value
    let matchingOption = this._filter(input)[0] || 'DEFAULT VALUE';
    // now set the best matching option 
    // or let's call it autoSelects best match option for an user
    this.autoInput.setValue(matchingOption);
  }, 300);
}
```

This way, we will be able to manipulate autocomplete input value on `matInput` focused out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, those issues are related to "bad" implementation of events and it would be better to use store frameworks IMO.
However, here is a solution that works quite well: When the focus out is fired by a click onto an autocomplete element, we can ignore it.

```
  focusOut(event: FocusEvent){
    if(event.relatedTarget && (event.relatedTarget as Element).tagName == 'MAT-OPTION') {
      // That means that the user clicked on an autocomplete element, so we need to ignore the fire event
      // otherwise we will call updated two times, in parallel
    } else {
      this.updated.emit({...});
    }
    this.descriptionFocusedOut.emit(...);
  }
```